# reference for principal part

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, reference-request, geometric-topology, nonlinear-analysis

I am not really familiar with the notion of principal part. I guess the following statement is true: (that I extracted it from sketch of a theorem)

Suppose $f=g+dh+dk$ on a smooth subset $U$ of $\Bbb R^n$ and  *principal part*  of $f$ and $dh+dk$ are equal to zero then
$$\int_{B(p,r)} f\ \mathsf{dvol}\sim\int_{B(p,r)} g\ \mathsf{dvol}.$$
Where  $p\in U$ and $B(p,r)$ is a disk of radius $r$ centered at $p$.

I am not sure about the exact statement. I would be grateful if someone could provide some references  (suitable for differential geometers if possible) that contains the above statement and its proof and some solved problems.

Comment: Is what you call principal part another name for differential?

Comment: @lcv: I am not sure. it is just a translation of French "partie principale".